# JSF 2.0 rapid web design tool

Tags: jsf-2

I'm learning about JSF 2.0, I want to know if there is a tool for rapid web design.
I looked around and found [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) but it seems not to be compatible with Glassfish v3 (it's the server I use by the way).

I'll apreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrimeFaces

http://www.primefaces.org/

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces is the best lightweight rapid web designing tool.